# Bob wants revenge on his evil boss

Tags: word, knowledge, story, geography

Bob wants revenge on his evil boss, so he devises a cunning plan.

He writes a request to visit three American cities, and then gets his boss to approve it.

Bob then instead travels to six locations, including Africa, Europe and Oceania.

Upon his return, Bob gives his boss a huge flight expenses bill.

Furiously, the boss checks the travel request again, and can do nothing but reluctantly agree to pay the eye-watering bill.

Little does anyone know, Bob made an amendment to the request after his boss signed it - he simply added three small dots.

What did the request originally look like, and where did Bob add the three dots?

Hint:

> The answer does not contain abbreviated state names.

Comment: What did his boss ever do to bob?

Comment: @PlaceReporter99 That might have to be a separate puzzle!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bob wrote:

> *Dear boss, I would like to visit London, Ohio; Algiers, Louisiana; Sydney, Florida.*

Boss assumes these requests are all for the American cities of these names.

Then he can put three dots to make the request:

> *Dear boss, I would like to visit London; Ohio; Algiers; Louisiana; Sydney; Florida.*

Comment: I like this idea. To make it a little more natural perhaps you could use (rot 13) pbzznf gheavat vagb frzvpbybaf, vafgrnq bs crevbqf.

Comment: @Carmeister Bingo. Nice work between you both. Happy to accept this answer once it's tidied up a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Bob requested to see, for example

> `Miami, Fl, Huntsville, Al, Chicago, Il`

making sure to use a font

> where the `l` can be made to look like an `i` by putting a dot above it.

Then, he visited those three cities in the US, and also

> Fi, a town in Mali, Ål, towns/villages in Sweden/Norway, and Ii, a train station in Japan.

There are actually some more names which would work with the same pattern on Wikipedia:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_short_place_names

Comment: You are close, but are they all dots?

Comment: I will also add: rot13(Zl vagraqrq nafjre qbrfa'g hfr nooerivngrq fgngr anzrf, ohg creuncf gurer'f n inyvq nafjre lbhe jnl.)

Comment: Are there really fonts where a lowercase `l` could be turned into a lowercase `i` like that? Usually the issue is that a lowercase `l` already looks a lot like an _uppercase_ `I`, and there's no room for the dot there without it looking really awkward (or turning into some non-English letter, e.g. the Turkish `İ`)

Comment: Please read the hint

Comment: @PlaceReporter99, [it was added after this answer was posted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/120492/revisions)

Answer (score 3):

My guess (which may not be right but I felt its cunning, requires a *not so smart* boss, and it fits) -

> Bob had a world map with dots on the places he wanted to visit in his original request. After Boss signed it, he added 3 more dots to add 3 more locations for 3 different countries/continents. So, the answer to where did Bob added those extra 3 dots is, on the **MAP**

Original Request -

> Dear Boss,
>  Following are the places, marked with red dots, I would be visiting. Please approve.
>  [image]

Modified Request -

> Dear Boss,
>  Following are the places, marked with red dots, I would be visiting. Please approve.
>  [image]

Comment: I am not quite sure about its usage but note that there's [tag:word] tag.

Comment: @ACB Yup. I had seen it. OP also had a riddle tag for the last puzzle they posted and it was not relevant and there was a riddle tag to this as well. So went with this. I've edited to fit the tag as well. Btw, I am pretty sure this may not be the answer, but well, who knows :)

Comment: Nice answer, but I am after a written set of words that have been modified by adding three dots. In other words, the answer can be typed.

Comment: @rybo111 Yup. Got it. I have some ideas. r13(yvxr znl or ä sbe n be y gb v. V nz whfg jrnx ng trbtencul :Q)